# TSV processing with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a TSV file as follows. (Well it's saved as a csv). It was created by running paste on 2 files and saving the output in another file. Therefore the columns are actually separated by tabs.

This is this file structure

```
Quantity1 Value1 Value2 Value3 ...Valuen
Quantity2 Value1 Value2 Value3 ...ValueN
....
....
Quantityn Value1 Value2 Value3 ...Valuen
```

I want to add just 3 more columns to the file which will print out the min, max, and the 90th percentile of each row in 3 columns at the end.

Since the files were created by a Ruby script i figured they should also be processed by a ruby script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to read the file, add the needed columns for each line, and write it again, something like this:

```
CSV.open('path_to_new_file.csv', 'wb', col_sep: "\t") do |new_csv|
  CSV.foreach('path_to_src_file.csv', col_sep: "\t") do |row|
    sorted_values = row[1..-1].sort
    min = sorted_values.first
    max = sorted_values.last
    ninetieth_percentile = sorted_values[(sorted_values.length * 0.9).floor]
    new_csv << row + [min, max, ninetieth_percentile]
  end
end
```

For more information about processing CSVs in ruby, see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Comment: Actually shouldn't nintieth percentile be 
`ninetieth_percentile = sorted_values[((sorted_values.length * 0.9).ceil)-1]`

because the indices of the sorted vals start from 0 and not 1?

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh - I think you are right. I've changed it from `.ceil` to `.floor`...